# Different associated object key in static framework when accessing outside

Tags: ios, swift, associated-object

I wrote codes like below. this code is in static framework.

```swift
private struct AssociatedKeys {
  static var someKey = "someKey"
}

extension SomeClass {
  public var someProperty: String? {
    get { 
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.someKey) as? String
    }
    set {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.someKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
  }
}
```

`someProperty` is defined with `public`, so another framework can access to `SomeClass.someProperty`.

but when another framework accesses to `SomeClass.someProperty`, `&AssociatedKeys.someKey` value in each get/set clause are different. So we cannot get valid `someProperty` value. It always returns `nil`.

this issue is not reproduced when the code is in dynamic framework.
and it is reproduced on iOS 14.2 simulator, but not reproduced on iOS 16.0 simulator.

is this about `UnsafeRawPointer` operation? anyone can help us?

when the property is not `public`(ex. `internal`, `fileprivate`, `private`), the associated keys were same. so it seems that it is reproduced when the property is opened.

Comment: The fact that this occurs in 14.2 but not 16 suggests it's an Apple bug that has been fixed. Does it reproduce on iOS 16 at all?

Comment: hmm.. actually it is also vague. some teammates said they can reproduce the issue on iOS 16.2 devices.